# How to create a function in DB2 that returns the value of a sequence?

Tags: sql, function, db2

How to create a function in DB2 that obtains a value from a sequence and returns it?

It should be possible to use that function in select or insert statement, e.g:

```
select my_func() from xxx
insert into xxx values(my_func())
```

Basically I am using the sequence value in a complex formula, and I'd like to encapsulate the calculation inside a function.

Edit: I am not asking how to simply get next value from sequence.

Comment: I am not as familiar with DB2 as SQL Server so apologies if the links are not helpful. This article discusses the creation of [DB2 sequences][1], which I assume you are familiar with (I was not). However, based on original poster in this [discussion][2], it doesn't appear that one can consume a sequence from a function call.  That is in-line with the SQL Server restrictions that user-defined functions cannot modify the database state.


  [1]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html#section4
  [2]: http://bit.ly/mvoGjY

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION "MYSCHEMA"."MY_FUNC"(PARAM1 VARCHAR(4000))
     RETURNS INT
SPECIFIC SQL110520140321900 BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE VAR1 INT;
     DECLARE VAR2 INT;
     SET VAR1  = NEXTVAL FOR MY_SEQ;
     SET VAR2 = VAR1 + 2000; --or whatever magic you want to do
     RETURN VAR2;
END
```

To try it out:

```
SELECT MY_FUNC('aa') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```