# How can I call a function in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have implement a function fn_getDate()

I want to use it as the following

```
select fn_getDate() as 'currenct_date'
```

so how shall I call it

Comment: Have you tried `select fn_getDate() as 'currenct_date' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`. Found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6072328/1385896)

Comment: @FilipeSilva - You should probably make that an answer... Maria - why are you needing to call the function on its own?  Are you not querying other tables?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try it the way you've posted? In what SCHEMA is the function, and is that SCHEMA on your library list?

Comment: select fn_getDate() as 'currenct_date' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select fn_getDate() as 'currenct_date' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: That should be `"currenct_date"` not `'currenct_date'` because identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes not single quotes.